# Why doesn't my algorithm for inverting character values work when they're stored in a Delphi XE2 ShortString?

Tags: delphi, unicode

I have the following code :

```
user_s.username := EnDecrypt(Edit_username.Text);
```

The function is the following :

```
function EnDeCrypt(const Value : String) : String;
 var
 CharIndex : integer;
begin
 Result := Value;
 for CharIndex := 1 to Length(Value) do
Result[CharIndex] := chr(not(ord(Value[CharIndex])));
end;
```

the type of variable is :

```
TUser = record
 access: char;
 username: string[25];
 password: string[25];
end;
```

In Delphi 2007 it works, in Delphi XE2 it fails. The curious thing is that it encrypts/decrypts well the password if it is 123456789. The issue must be related with unicode and the use of shortstring. I hope there is some way to make it work in Delphi XE2 as well..

Comment: That's obfuscation at best, not encryption. It doesn't even have a key.

Comment: i'd definitely suggest you be rather carefull with using Ord and Chr with UnicodeChar type in Delphi. You'd better use direct typecast like Word(var-char) and WideChar(var-word).  QC100685

Comment: It would probably just be easier to remove that *encryption*. What makes you think it's doing you any good? Do you need to *encrypt* in Unicode Delphi and decrypt in ANSI Delphi, or vice versa? If not then either simply remove the *encryption* or add some real encryption.

Comment: Inverting bits is not encryption. And this approach can be problematic if carried into the unicode world.  You might create some weird cases like surrogate pairs and stuff, just by inverting bits.  Abandon this crappy "non-encryption" is a better solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace `String` type with `AnsiString`, and `Char` with `AnsiChar`, and the code will work exactly as in Delphi 2007. (`String[25]` should not be altered, though.) Of course, you will not get Unicode support.

Comment: That is the issue. I have done before this and i lose unicode support. Is there any solution that preserves unicode support?

Comment: @Moore Perhaps you should describe what you want to achieve. From my point of view, your code doesn't offer anything over `result := value;`.

Comment: @Moore: I haven't really time to study your algorithm, so I don't know how it works. But surely you know that. Perhaps you should abandon `string[25]` (a ShortString, which is Ansi, not Unicode) in favour for regular `string` (which is Unicode). You might also need to take into consideration that in Unicode 1 character is 2 bytes.

Comment: at least 2 bytes. Current Windows uses UTF-16, not UCS-2 :-)

Comment: The issue is the shortstring. I should definitely abandon it. I thought there maybe some way to fix it to accept unicode strings. thnx for the help..

Comment: @Moore: No, that is (unfortunately) impossible. It would be rather convenient at times.

Comment: a bit convenient, but given SetString procedure, usual record size+data-array would suffice too. Given that they changed string type yet again to carry codepages, they'd had to do the same with hypothetical Unicode Short Strings as well. And then binary layout would be broken.  I'd maybe tried to store UTF8 strings in ShortString at the price of less possible length, but keeping the record tpye intact.

Comment: BTW AnsiString chars are also not always 1 byte length. Ref: System.Classes.NextChar, System.AnsiStrings.NextCharIndex, System.SysUtils.StrNextChar and a lot of nearby functions